# Getting npm error while installing xmldom

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting npm error as below

> npm install xmldom
>   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom
>
> npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:670:11)
>   npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:661:19)
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>   npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program File
>       s (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "xmldom"
>   npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\panugasu
>       npm ERR! node -v v0.6.18
>       npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.21
>       npm ERR! syscall connect
>       npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
>       npm ERR! message connect ECONNREFUSED
>       npm ERR! errno {}
>       npm ERR!
>       npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
>       npm ERR!     C:\Users\panugasu\npm-debug.log
>       npm not ok

But with the same setup the installation go fine for other modules for example

> npm install xml2js
>   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xml2js
>   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sax
>   xml2js@0.1.14 ./node_modules/xml2js
>   └── sax@0.4.0

Need immediate help on how to solve this...

The below is what I get when I visit the url https://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom

> {"_id":"xmldom","_rev":"53-b06f4b669d712be646c86109995af18d","name":"xmldom","description":"A W3C Standard XML DOM(Level2 CORE) implementation and parser(DOMParser/XMLSerializer).","dist-tags":{"latest":"0.1.11"},"versions":{"0.1.0":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.0","description":"A W3C Standard based DOMParser and XMLSerializer (DOM Level2 CORE). ","keywords":["javascript","XML","DOM","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://code.google.com/p/lite/issues/list"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"repositories":[{"type":"svn","url":"http://lite.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Lite/web/scripts/org/xidea/lite/util/xml"}],"implements":[],"dependencies":{},"engines":{"node":">=0.5"},"directories":{"lib":"./"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.0","devDependencies":{},"_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.1.0-alpha-2","_nodeVersion":"v0.6.3","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"ccf582a2b3b9ada6dbde027d36ca8a3fdcdc3d2e","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.0.tgz"}},"0.1.1":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.1","description":"A W3C Standard based DOMParser and XMLSerializer (DOM Level2 CORE). ","keywords":["javascript","XML","DOM","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://code.google.com/p/lite/issues/list"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"repositories":[{"type":"svn","url":"http://lite.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Lite/web/scripts/org/xidea/lite/util/xml"}],"implements":[],"dependencies":{},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"directories":{"lib":"./"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.1","devDependencies":{},"_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"bb091356c9a9d86a18bca88199deffc52c032e66","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.1.tgz"}},"0.1.2":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.2","description":"A W3C Standard based DOMParser and XMLSerializer (DOM Level2 CORE). ","keywords":["javascript","XML","DOM","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://code.google.com/p/lite/issues/list"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"repositories":[{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"}],"implements":[],"dependencies":{},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"directories":{"lib":"./"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.2","devDependencies":{},"_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"39bb0ccdc55d81d5906a2616c2fb024795ca9978","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.2.tgz"}},"0.1.3":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.3","description":"A W3C Standard based DOMParser and XMLSerializer (DOM Level2 CORE). ","keywords":["javascript","XML","DOM","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[{"name":"Yaron Naveh","email":"yaronn01@gmail.com","url":"http://webservices20.blogspot.com/"},{"name":"Harutyun Amirjanyan","email":"amirjanyan@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/nightwing"}],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://github.com/jindw/xmldom/issues"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"repositories":[{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"}],"implements":[],"dependencies":{},"devDependencies":{"wows":"*"},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"directories":{"lib":"./"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.3","_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"0df9b4bc6c13e0cc8c02b87720cc26712be4f5d0","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.3.tgz"}},"0.1.4":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.4","description":"A W3C Standard based DOMParser and XMLSerializer (DOM Level2 CORE). ","keywords":["javascript","XML","DOM","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[{"name":"Yaron Naveh","email":"yaronn01@gmail.com","url":"http://webservices20.blogspot.com/"},{"name":"Harutyun Amirjanyan","email":"amirjanyan@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/nightwing"}],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://github.com/jindw/xmldom/issues"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"repositories":[{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"}],"implements":[],"dependencies":{},"devDependencies":{"wows":"*"},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"directories":{"lib":"./"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.4","_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"f3d1ef1705ed502c73a0b52c2675161fb1c2319d","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.4.tgz"}},"0.1.5":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.5","description":"A W3C Standard based DOMParser and XMLSerializer (DOM Level2 CORE). ","keywords":["javascript","XML","DOM","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[{"name":"Yaron Naveh","email":"yaronn01@gmail.com","url":"http://webservices20.blogspot.com/"},{"name":"Harutyun Amirjanyan","email":"amirjanyan@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/nightwing"}],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://github.com/jindw/xmldom/issues"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"repositories":[{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"}],"implements":[],"dependencies":{},"devDependencies":{"wows":"*"},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"directories":{"lib":"./"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.5","_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"ca8ddeb9252902c6e59ce1de0e0248a8bdc59157","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.5.tgz"}},"0.1.6":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.6","description":"A W3C Standard based DOMParser and XMLSerializer (DOM Level2 CORE). ","keywords":["javascript","XML","DOM","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[{"name":"Yaron Naveh","email":"yaronn01@gmail.com","url":"http://webservices20.blogspot.com/"},{"name":"Harutyun Amirjanyan","email":"amirjanyan@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/nightwing"}],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://github.com/jindw/xmldom/issues"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"repositories":[{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"}],"implements":[],"dependencies":{},"devDependencies":{"wows":"*"},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"directories":{"lib":"./"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.6","_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"1e86209548bbaff7ccd8e7b0f441a8fbef551cd7","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.6.tgz"}},"0.1.7":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.7","description":"A W3C Standard based DOMParser and XMLSerializer (DOM Level2 CORE). ","keywords":["javascript","XML","DOM","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[{"name":"Yaron Naveh","email":"yaronn01@gmail.com","url":"http://webservices20.blogspot.com/"},{"name":"Harutyun Amirjanyan","email":"amirjanyan@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/nightwing"}],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://github.com/jindw/xmldom/issues"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"repositories":[{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"}],"implements":[],"dependencies":{},"devDependencies":{"wows":"*"},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"directories":{"lib":"./"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.7","_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"c338f1cd9893a623d1603c0a7fea7df439a120b8","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.7.tgz"}},"0.1.8":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.8","description":"A W3C Standard based DOMParser and XMLSerializer (DOM Level2 CORE). ","keywords":["javascript","XML","DOM","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[{"name":"Yaron Naveh","email":"yaronn01@gmail.com","url":"http://webservices20.blogspot.com/"},{"name":"Harutyun Amirjanyan","email":"amirjanyan@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/nightwing"}],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://github.com/jindw/xmldom/issues"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"repositories":[{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"}],"implements":[],"dependencies":{},"devDependencies":{"wows":"*"},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"directories":{"lib":"./"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.8","_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"fdffec08120fea390d6482a9f34e6d167cb8b207","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.8.tgz"}},"0.1.9":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.9","description":"A W3C Standard based DOMParser and XMLSerializer (DOM Level2 CORE). ","keywords":["javascript","XML","DOM","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[{"name":"Yaron Naveh","email":"yaronn01@gmail.com","url":"http://webservices20.blogspot.com/"},{"name":"Harutyun Amirjanyan","email":"amirjanyan@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/nightwing"}],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://github.com/jindw/xmldom/issues"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"repositories":[{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"}],"implements":[],"dependencies":{},"devDependencies":{"vows":"*"},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"directories":{"lib":"./"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.9","_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"d5831a5770541f69353b261c6adc88ccd1d12073","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.9.tgz"}},"0.1.10":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.10","description":"A W3C Standard XML DOM(Level2 CORE) implementation and parser(DOMParser/XMLSerializer).","keywords":["XML","DOM","parser","javascript","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"author":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://www.xidea.org"},"homepage":"https://github.com/jindw/xmldom","repository":{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","scripts":{"test":"./test"},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"dependencies":{},"devDependencies":{},"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[{"name":"Yaron Naveh","email":"yaronn01@gmail.com","url":"http://webservices20.blogspot.com/"},{"name":"Harutyun Amirjanyan","email":"amirjanyan@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/nightwing"}],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://github.com/jindw/xmldom/issues"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.10","_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"021f55b75f815ccfbbc59e1a7a40484ba100e234","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.10.tgz"},"directories":{}},"0.1.11":{"name":"xmldom","version":"0.1.11","description":"A W3C Standard XML DOM(Level2 CORE) implementation and parser(DOMParser/XMLSerializer).","keywords":["XML","DOM","parser","javascript","DOMParser","XMLSerializer"],"author":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://www.xidea.org"},"homepage":"https://github.com/jindw/xmldom","repository":{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"},"main":"./dom-parser.js","scripts":{"test":"./test"},"engines":{"node":">=0.1"},"dependencies":{},"devDependencies":{},"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"contributors":[{"name":"Yaron Naveh","email":"yaronn01@gmail.com","url":"http://webservices20.blogspot.com/"},{"name":"Harutyun Amirjanyan","email":"amirjanyan@gmail.com","url":"https://github.com/nightwing"},{"name":"bigeasy","email":"alan@prettyrobots.com","url":"http://www.prettyrobots.com/"}],"bugs":{"email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://github.com/jindw/xmldom/issues"},"licenses":[{"type":"LGPL","url":"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}],"_npmUser":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"},"_id":"xmldom@0.1.11","_engineSupported":true,"_npmVersion":"1.0.103","_nodeVersion":"v0.5.10","_defaultsLoaded":true,"dist":{"shasum":"d8227c85bdf5197ed9b5c9d12319e3bcdd6d2eac","tarball":"http://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.11.tgz"},"directories":{}}},"readme":null,"maintainers":[{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org"}],"time":{"0.1.0":"2012-01-06T09:49:42.641Z","0.1.1":"2012-01-10T07:18:18.313Z","0.1.2":"2012-02-03T10:49:02.984Z","0.1.3":"2012-05-22T16:39:09.565Z","0.1.4":"2012-05-22T16:41:40.120Z","0.1.5":"2012-05-25T17:43:18.008Z","0.1.6":"2012-05-28T12:49:32.759Z","0.1.7":"2012-05-29T03:05:55.479Z","0.1.8":"2012-05-29T13:30:02.006Z","0.1.9":"2012-06-08T06:18:02.555Z","0.1.10":"2012-06-14T02:54:35.731Z","0.1.11":"2012-06-18T10:45:58.508Z"},"author":{"name":"jindw","email":"jindw@xidea.org","url":"http://www.xidea.org"},"repository":{"type":"git","url":"git://github.com/jindw/xmldom.git"}}

Comment: What happens when you visit https://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom from that system, either in a browser or you using a tool like curl to save the file.

Comment: I have updated the data I get when I visit the url on a browser

Comment: Looks like my problem is resolved. When I added a valid proxy value using npm set proxy, it went fine. Thanks...

Comment: Please accept the answer that fixes the issue so the next person who visits this question will find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the proxy config as stated in the error message:

```
npm config set proxy <proxy address>
```